# Netbeans 8.1 and Java - How to enable a checkbox after the main form is displayed

Tags: java, events, netbeans

First, I have only been into Java for couple of months.  Delphi before that, and before that, Clipper (showing my age!).

I want to enable a checkbox when my program starts.  I have tried the following in the `WindowActivated Event` in **Netbeans** but it does nothing.

```
private void formWindowActivated(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt){                                     
    cbMyCheckbox.setEnabled(true);
}
```

I know it is firing because I set a breakpoint on it and see that it is being executed.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why isn't it enabled at initialization?

Comment: If I do that, the event won't fire when the program starts.  I have code in the checkbox's ActionPerformed event that sets a variable when the checkbox is En/Disabled.  I could click on it after the program starts but I wanted the program to be a little more elegant than that. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Place **cbMyCheckbox.setEnabled(true);** in the class constructor right after the call **initComponents();**

Like so

```
public class YourClass (){
    public YourClass() {
      initComponents();
      cbMyCheckbox.setEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Or you can select your chekbox and in the properties check the "selected" option
[image]

Answer (score 0):

try to do this code **cbMyCheckbox.setEnabled(true);** after calling the function **show();**

Comment: I do not have a function, show().  In main(), there is:  
public void run() {
   new frmMain().setVisible(true);
  cbMyCheckBox.setEnabled(true);
}
so I placed it after the setVisible() function, as shown above. Then I get the message:  Non-static variable cbMyCheckBox cannot be referenced from a static context.